# Converting i2c data to string in Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, i2c

I'm using a Raspberry Pi to read light data from a BH1750 light sensor, and ultimately storing that data in a SQLite database.

The problem that I'm having is the data being passed through to the database is showing `function light at 0x76c12bb0`

I want the actual lux data reading to be passed through as a string, so I'll need to define the light reading, correct?

Here's what I have:

```
DEVICE     = 0x23 # Default device I2C address
POWER_DOWN = 0x00 # No active state
POWER_ON   = 0x01 # Power on
RESET      = 0x07 # Reset data register value
ONE_TIME_HIGH_RES_MODE = 0x20

bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

def convertToNumber(data):
  # Simple function to convert 2 bytes of data
  # into a decimal number
  return ((data[1] + (256 * data[0])) / 1.2)

def light(addr=DEVICE):
  data = bus.read_i2c_block_data(addr,ONE_TIME_HIGH_RES_MODE)
  return convertToNumber(data)
```

And then in my main() I have:

```
print (""), light, " lux"
```

Comment: You call a function like `light()`.  If you forget the parentheses -- which you have -- you are simply passing a reference to the function itself.

Comment: @larsks, post the answer :)